# (MVC) Trying to join a table it self by LinQ for display multiple language

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am trying to use LinQ to join a table itself, in order to display different columns in different session. In this case is when the LanguageId is "en" the "EnglishName" columns should be assigned to "Name". It always shows the error "cannot implicitly convert type...". I dont' know how to fix this code. Pls see the code bellow and help. Many tks.

**MemberDao**

```
public List<MemberViewModel> ListNewMember(int top, string languageId)
        {

            if (languageId == "en")
            {
                var model1 = from a in db.Members
                            join b in db.Members
                            on a.MemberId equals b.MemberId
                            select new MemberViewModel()
                            {
                                MemberId = a.MemberId,
                                Name = a.EnglishName,
                                Status = a.Status,
                                CreatedDate = a.CreatedDate
                            };
                IQueryable<MemberViewModel> model2 = model1;
                model2 = model2.Where(x => x.Status == true).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).Take(top).ToList();
            }
            return db.Members.Where(x => x.Status == true).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).Take(top).ToList();
        }
```

**MemberController**

```
using GBVNET.Common;
using Model.Dao;
using Models.Dao;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace GBVNET.Controllers
{
    public class MemberController : BaseClientController
    {

        //[ChildActionOnly]
        //[OutputCache(Duration = 3600 * 24)]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var slideDao = new SlideDao();
            var currentCulture = Session[CommonConstants.CurrentCulture].ToString();
            ViewBag.ChildrenSlides = slideDao.ListChildrenSlide(1, currentCulture);

            var categoryDao = new CategoryDao();
            ViewBag.DocumentCategory = categoryDao.DocumentCategory(1, currentCulture);
            ViewBag.ContactCategory = categoryDao.ContactCategory(1, currentCulture);

            var model = new MemberDao().ListNewMember(5, currentCulture);
            return View(model);
        }


        public ActionResult Detail(int id)
        {
            var slideDao = new SlideDao();
            var currentCulture = Session[CommonConstants.CurrentCulture].ToString();
            ViewBag.ChildrenSlides = slideDao.ListChildrenSlide(1, currentCulture);

            var categoryDao = new CategoryDao();
            ViewBag.DocumentCategory = categoryDao.DocumentCategory(1, currentCulture);
            ViewBag.ContactCategory = categoryDao.ContactCategory(1, currentCulture);

            var member = new MemberDao().ViewDetail(id);
            return View(member);
        }


    }
}
```

This is the screenshot of the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9qB2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I fixed them all by change the code as bellow:

**MemberDao**

```
public List<MemberViewModel> ListNewMember(int top, string languageId)
        {

            if (languageId == "en")
            {
                IEnumerable<MemberViewModel> model = from a in db.Members
                            join b in db.Members
                            on a.MemberId equals b.MemberId
                            select new MemberViewModel()
                            {
                                MemberId = a.MemberId,
                                Name = b.EnglishName,
                                Status = a.Status,
                                Logo = a.Logo,
                                Email = a.Email,
                                Address = a.Address,
                                Banner = a.Banner,
                                Facebook = a.Facebook,
                                Description = b.EnglishDescription
                            };
                model = model.Where(x => x.Status == true).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).Take(top).ToList();
                return model.Where(x => x.Status == true).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).Take(top).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                IEnumerable<MemberViewModel> model = from a in db.Members
                        join b in db.Members
                        on a.MemberId equals b.MemberId
                        select new MemberViewModel()
                        {
                            MemberId = a.MemberId,
                            Name = b.Name,
                            Status = a.Status,
                            Logo = a.Logo,
                            Email = a.Email,
                            Address = a.Address,
                            Banner = a.Banner,
                            Facebook = a.Facebook,
                            Description = a.Description
                        };
                model = model.Where(x => x.Status == true).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).Take(top).ToList();
                return model.Where(x => x.Status == true).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).Take(top).ToList();
            }

        }
```